# python in VS code : RuntimeError: can't start new thread

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code, runtime-error

I'm running into a RuntimeError with my Python 3.7 script in VS code.
I have different errors if I run it in debug mode (F5) or without debug (ctrl-F5).

I'm a beginner with Python and VS code. This error is not really meaningful to me.
When searching for similar question/problem, I've found that it's sometimes linked to trying to launch too many threads. But I don't create thread on purpose, it might be some background stuff though linked to VSCode.
The code is basicaly a for loop iterating over a dataset and plotting graph, saving it then closing it. So I don't see an obvious memory overusage as I close the plot at the end of each iteration.

I don't know where to look, or what to monitor to further investigate.
I'm not posting reproductible code as I believe the error happens on the whole project only, and depends also on the IDE.

Thanks for your help !

Here are the error logs with and without debug mode:

With debug :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "[...]\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "[...]\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_trace_dispatch_regular.py", line 203, in trace_dispatch
    py_db.enable_tracing(thread_trace_func)
  File "[...]\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1066, in enable_tracing
    pydevd_tracing.SetTrace(thread_trace_func)
  File "[...]\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_tracing.py", line 83, in SetTrace
    if set_trace_to_threads(tracing_func, thread_idents=[thread.get_ident()], create_dummy_thread=False) == 0:
  File "[...]\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.11.1422169775\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd_tracing.py", line 344, in set_trace_to_threads
    start_new_thread(increase_tracing_count, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

Without debug :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]main.py", line 44, in <module>
    visu_rmotor(data, train, debug)
  File "[...]visu_rmotor.py", line 83, in visu_rmotor
    save_figure('rmotor', train, door)
  File "[...]process_data.py", line 50, in save_figure
    plt.savefig(save_file_path)
  File "[...]matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 966, in savefig
    res = fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]matplotlib\figure.py", line 3015, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "[...]matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2261, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "[...]matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1669, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 508, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "[...]matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 401, in draw
    self.renderer = self.get_renderer(cleared=True)
  File "[...]matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 417, in get_renderer
    self.renderer = RendererAgg(w, h, self.figure.dpi)
  File "[...]matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 91, in __init__
    self._renderer = _RendererAgg(int(width), int(height), dpi)
MemoryError: In RendererAgg: Out of memory
```

Edit : stripped down my code to this, which will crash at "door=250" and using about 2Gb of RAM

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

door=0
while(1):
    door +=1
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex='all', figsize=(11.25, 6), num=10, clear=True)

    print(door)

    fig.clear() # trying every solution found on stackexchange to unload and free memory !
    fig.clf()
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()                                 
    del fig
```

Comment: Juste tried another solution by assigning a number to the matplotlib figure and set clear=True. It still crashes but with a different error now: Exception has occurred: TclError
not enough free memory for image buffer
  File "[...]\main.py", line 44, in <module>
    visu_rmotor(data, train, debug)

Comment: Have you monitored your memory usage while the program is running?

Comment: spot on ! it is indeed increasing until it's using about 2Gb for this script and then crashes (there are still 4Gb of free RAM overhead). I'm already using fig.clear() fig.clf() and plt.close(). What else could I do to free the memory used by the figure of the current iteration ?

Comment: You should post your code you may have some sort of infinite loop in your code

Comment: I stripped my code down to what I think is bare minimum to reproduce the memory leak, I'll edit my question to add it.

Comment: I don't use VS Code. Does it run in the browser or does it run Jupyter, which I know is in the browser? That said, at least in the case of Jupyter, garbage collection (and releasing memory) doesn't work, even if you try to manage it manually. Try download PyCharm (the free version) to run the code. I know the code which eats memory in Jupyter, works fine in PyCharm, where memory release and garbage collection work without issue.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney : VS Code runs as a standalone software on my windows 10 machine, not in a browser. I'm not able to change IDE unfortunately.

Comment: Switching the IDE is just for testing

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney : you're right it's a good idea to try it in a different IDE. I tried the stripped code on Jupyter and it failed at door=18375. Also I tried it on my personnal computer, and it failed at door=369. It seems the memory usage increase is very low on Jupyter compared to VS Code, even though it should not increase at all. So I can see it depends on the environnement, but every trial has failed due to memory filling up. What am I missing to free memory at the end of each iteration?

Comment: It will always eventually fail on Jupyter (for memory consumption), that's why I suggested PyCharm, which doesn't usually have the same issue.